# Problem when deploying contract using Remix on Testnet

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I tried to deploy a contract to Testnet with Remix (all Testnet return the same message) and I got this error:

```
Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (30000000) or always failing transaction" }
```

But when I tried to deploy it in BSC Mainnet everything works fine with no errors. Any suggestions?

this is the relevant code

```
contract artemis is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    // ...

    constructor() public {
        _rOwned[_msgSender()] = _rTotal;

        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router =
            IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);
        // Create a Pancakeswap pair for this new token
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
            .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());

        // set the rest of the contract variables
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;

        //exclude owner and this contract from fee
        _isExcludedFromFee[owner()] = true;
        _isExcludedFromFee[address(this)] = true;

        emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

I upload the whole code here because its to  long.

[code](http://depositfiles.com/files/y9aomy21z)

Comment: Please edit your question and share the source code of your contract. The "always failing transaction" is the more probable reason stated in the error message.

Answer (score 7):

```
IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router =
    IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);

// Create a Pancakeswap pair for this new token
uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory())
    .createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Router.WETH());
```

These lines in your constructor are trying to interact with a contract that [exists](https://bscscan.com/address/0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F) on the mainnet. But you're on the testnet, where there's [no contract](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F) on this address.

As stated in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pancakeswap/comments/m1s3ki/pancakeswap_on_bsc_testnet/), the Pancake testnet router address is :

> **[0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1)**

So you need to replace the hardcoded address to this one.

Comment: Thanks for your help...i was really stuck over here...can you please tell me if there is a way to change the maxTxAmount  in my contract after i deployd .

Comment: @marvin I'm not sure what `maxTxAmount` you mean. If it's a variable with a setter function, you can execute the setter function to set the new value. If it's a constant (or a variable without a setter function), there's no way to change it, because the bytecode is immutable by design.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer..

uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;

i mean this...i dont think this si a constant...inside the contract it looks like this

    uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 5000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;

and i need to make it uint256 public _maxTxAmount = 1000000000 * 10**6 * 10**9;


Also is there another router address for ropsten network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the case of your code (posted to the original question), you can affect the `_maxTxAmount` with the `setMaxTxPercent()` function. Mind that the function has the `onlyOwner` modifier, so you can execute it only from the `owner` address... Pancakeswap is an opensource, so there's pretty high chance there is another instance of their router, but I'm not aware of any.